# Google Maps View Inflate Exception

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement a simple [Map with a Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker) which is giving me this error
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment`

I have crosschecked Gradle,Java & XML.
Heres by code:

**Logcat:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process:  com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1, PID: 22070
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1/com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5524)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630)
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                   at com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:19)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5524) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630) 
                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                   at com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:19) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2402) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5524) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630) 
                                                Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity that is not a Fragment
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:608)
                                                   at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
```

**Java :**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification
        // when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
        // and move the map's camera to the same location.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

**Gradle :**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    compile 'com.github.florent37:materialtextfield:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**XML:**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity" />
```

Comment: IIRC you can't use a Fragment as a root-level component in a layout file, none of the [documentation examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) have `fragment` as the root element. Try wrapping it in a Framelayout.

Comment: have you provided your complete code or do you have other classes as well?

Comment: @MichaelDodd In this google axample they have used fragment as root element and its working https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapwithmarker/MapsMarkerActivity.java

Comment: @NoumanCh Please refer this google example how they are doing it?https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapwithmarker/MapsMarkerActivity.java

Comment: @MichaelDodd Update : Check is updated link from google :  https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_maps.xml

Comment: @GeekWithGlasses And does that code compile on your machine without any changes? (Can't check myself at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.propelit.actionapps.propelit_rev1.HomeActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring `xmlns:android` and`xmlns:tools` twice?

Comment: forgot to delete while pasting as ans BTW thanks for your suggestion @MichaelDodd

Comment: @NileshRathod It worked but i wonder how this code is working -> https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/tutorials/MapWithMarker/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_maps.xml